# What do I do with the piano in the volcano?

Tags: seiklus

I am playing [seiklus](http://www.autofish.net/clysm/art/video_games/seiklus/) and got to the bit where there is a piano like object inside a volcano. I can jump on the keys and make music, and each key I hit also makes a different colour appear in the bottom of the two dots above the piano.

I can't seem to just walk any further, and there is nowhere I can really seem to jump to, either. What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember, the key positions and their colors are important to note as you'll be back later on. Have a go with the keys.

After you've had your fun, backtrack and go down the staircase. You should notice a big crack in the wall on the right once you reach a chain (I believe this is the one you climbed to get up). Head in and there should be an elevator waiting for you...

Don't forget the white orbs... gotta collect them all.